# In Python issubclass() unexpectedly complains about "Protocols with non-method members"

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocols, python-typing

I have tried the obvious way to check my protocol:

```py
from typing import Any, Protocol, runtime_checkable

@runtime_checkable
class SupportsComparison(Protocol):
    def __eq__(self, other: Any) -> bool:
        ...

issubclass(int, SupportsComparison)
```

Unfortunately the `issubclass()` call ends with an exception (Python 3.10.6 in Ubuntu 22.04):

```bash
$ python3.10 protocol_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "protocol_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    issubclass(object, SupportsComparison)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/abc.py", line 123, in __subclasscheck__
    return _abc_subclasscheck(cls, subclass)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py", line 1570, in _proto_hook
    raise TypeError("Protocols with non-method members"
TypeError: Protocols with non-method members don't support issubclass()
```

As you can see I added no non-method members to `SupportsComparison`. Is this a bug in the standard library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> A class that overrides `__eq__()` and does not define `__hash__()`
> will have its `__hash__()` implicitly set to `None`.

Therefore, in your case, you have the implicit non-method member `SupportsComparison.__hash__ = None`. You can fix it by declaring `__hash__` explicitly:

```py
from typing import Any, Protocol, runtime_checkable

@runtime_checkable
class SupportsComparison(Protocol):
    def __eq__(self, other: Any) -> bool:
        ...

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        ...

issubclass(int, SupportsComparison)
```

Comment: I did not encounter this implicit setting of `__hash__` yet. Thank you! I think this could be a limitation to Python's protocols. I think in some cases we can require `__eq__()` without having specific requirements on `__hash__`.

Comment: That's true. Though I think the bigger problem is that it will be unexpected for most users. I think in practice it's rarely important to require `__eq__` because by default it's inherited from `object`. So even if you make an empty `class Test: ...`, you will have `issubclass(Test, SupportsComparison)`.